# sql server Query to find exactly 1 year difference

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Need to disable an user in the database (SQL Server) on exact completion of 1 year.

For this I have the following query which would executed by a job on timely basis.

```
update TOCustDetails
set IsActive = 0
where DATEDIFF(DAY,CreatedOn,(DATEADD (YEAR,1,CreatedOn)))  >= 365
```

But its failing on few points like :
1. Leap year handling is not done, One can do it by checking year, I know
2. I prefer not to have hardcoding like 365 or so
3. Also its not accurate because I need accuracy level up to second at least.
 +/- 1 second delay would be fine.

Can anyone please advice me on this?

Comment: My local machine do not have SQL, but can you try this query in where part `DATEADD(YEAR,1,CreatedOn) <= getdate()`. If it works then I will put it as an answer

Comment: DATEADD(YEAR,1,CreatedOn) < getdate() seems like it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question you are trying to check if expiry date has elapsed or not, so get expiry date and check if it has occured like below :

```
DATEADD(YEAR,1,CreatedOn) <= getdate()
```

Here we are calculating expiry date from `DATEADD(YEAR,1,CreatedOn)` and it will be as accurate as CreatedOn and compare it with current date `getdate()`